# Just another Azure AD migration

Tags: azure, entra-id

I work in a small office with approx 25 users, right now we have an on prem AD with office365 using dir sync, we have a mix of Mac and pc. Right now we have a file storage on site but most users use OneDrive for storage so we are going to move to a full cloud file storage. The only other thing we use AD for, other than authentication, we use radius for wifi.

Now my question, does it sound feasible to move to full azure ad P2 and intune with a vm server running radius and azure ad domain services and a site to site vpn tunnel?

Thanks

Comment: What is your end goal? Azure AD is not a replacement for on-premise AD. You could run a full Windows Server instance with AD in the cloud and a site-to-site VPN. But Azure AD and Intune is by no means a replacement for active directory and group policy.

Comment: I agree with @Appleoddity. For example this RADIUS authentication would not be possible without full AD. And for internal networks I'd recommend authentication with computer accounts instead of usernames and passwords. All this needs a domain controller, but it could well be in Azure private cloud. For joining new computers to AD you'd better have a *layer 2* site-to-site VPN.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to remember here is that AAD DS is not meant as a replacement for your on-premises domain. It exists to help you migrate legacy applications to run in Azure, that require a full AD implementation, it was never intended as a replacement for your whole AD. It also has a number of restrictions in place that you don't get with full AD.

If you use AAD DS and your internet connection goes down you have lost all your authentication, so if you do go down that route you would need to make sure you have a reliable, redundant connection.